Tamron SP 150-600mm Di VC USD G2 - what could cause strange seeking/searching behavior?
I bought a used, like new Tamron SP 150-600 Di VC USD G2 from a reliable source.
I read that it is compatible with the Nikon D5600 APS-C camera. When trying it out, the lens has some strange seeking/searching issues that I cannot pinpoint to one specific function. It seems to be related to various camera functions. Sometimes it keeps cycling when the LCD screen comes on or when I hit the review button or when I turn on the camera, until I depress the shutter button halfway. Is this a problem lens or compatibility issues?

This question really needs a more detailed description of your "strange issues".

Are you basing the "seeking/searching" description on noises the lens is making when the camera is turned on or awakened from "sleep"? Or on what you see in the viewfinder when activating the camera's autofocus?

It is a communication issue, and probably a fault with the lens. But it could be just the combination is a little loose at the lens mounts.
Tamron's website says the lens is completely compatible with the D5600. It also says that there was a firmware update to enable function with the Nikon FTZ adapter... i.e. that should make no difference for your use.

It sounds like you're basing the "seeking/searching" description on what you hear when the camera is first turned on or when the camera is "awakened" from standby?
If so, then this is completely normal. What you are hearing is not the autofocus motor, it's the miniature gyros for the VR (Vibration Reduction) turning on and spinning up to speed. Pressing the shutter button halfway normally (when several menu items are left at their default settings) activates the autofocus system and locks the VR system into aiming the lens' optics in a steady direction.
